# Syntax issue with UIPickerView Swift 5

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I've been researching various ways of creating a UIPickerView and every time I face the same issues:

**I get the error:**

> Type 'timeselectviewController' does not conform to protocol
>   'UIPickerViewDataSource'

and the pickerView function always get the warning:

> Instance method 'pickerView(pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:)'
>   nearly matches optional requirement
>   'pickerView(_:titleForRow:forComponent:)' of protocol
>   'UIPickerViewDelegate'

**Here is the code so far:**

```
import UIKit

class timeselectviewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var gradeTextField: UITextField!
var gradePicker: UIPickerView!

let gradePickerValues = ["5. Klasse", "6. Klasse", "7. Klasse"]

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return gradePickerValues.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return gradePickerValues[row]
}

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
        gradeTextField.text = gradePickerValues[row]
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        gradePicker = UIPickerView()

        gradePicker.dataSource = self
        gradePicker.delegate = self

        gradeTextField.inputView = gradePicker
        gradeTextField.text = gradePickerValues[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the missing `_`.

Comment: A good use case for letting Xcode do code completion for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding the “does not conform to protocol” warning, that’s because the protocol has certain required methods. If you tap on the warning, it will offer you the opportunity to add method “stubs”:

   [image]

   If you choose the “fix” option, it will add the missing required [`UIPickerViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdatasource) delegate methods:

   [image]

   You obviously have to write the code for those methods, but it will show you precisely which methods are missing and what you have to do.

   Note, it’s [`numberOfComponents(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdatasource/1614377-numberofcomponents), not  `numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView:)`. What you have appears to be the old Swift 2 syntax.
2. Regarding the "nearly matches optional requirement” warning:

   Both [`titleForRow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614384-pickerview) and [`didSelectRow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614371-pickerview) are missing the `_` [argument label](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166) for the first parameter. They are, respectively:

   ```
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? { ... }
   ```

   and

   ```
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) { ... }`
   ```

   Note the `_` argument label, like you had for `numberOfRowsInComponent`.

   Whenever you see a warning like this, carefully review the documentation for the protocol in question ([`UIPickerViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate) in this case).

   Often, if you tap on the warning, it will even give you an option to have Xcode fix the method signature for you. Choose the option that says “... to satisfy this requirement”, not the one that says “... to silence this warning”:

   [image: satisfy this requirement]

Bottom line, whenever you see warnings about missing protocol requirements and/or “nearly matches” warnings, either try the fixes that the compiler suggests and/or double check the protocol documentation.